# Multiple jQuery Instances and jQuery plugins generate Errors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using two jQuery plugins in my site color box popup plugin and coda content slider
1- http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/
2- http://www.ndoherty.biz/demos/coda-slider/2.0/

It seems that both conflict with each other. I have added the required JS file in this order

```
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/colorbox/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>

<!-- Coda Slider  -->
<link type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/coda/codastyle.css"    rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/coda /js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/coda/js/jquery.coda-slider-2.0.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery Colorbox Popup  -->
<link media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/colorbox/colorbox.css" />
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
```

Independently both plugins work fine. But when used together I get different errors in Firebug. This is the error I am getting right now

```
jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def] is not a function
[Break On This Error] return jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def](x, t, b, c, d);
```

These plugins definitely conflict each other. 
Is there any solution to this ? Can use multiple jQuery instances?

Comment: BTW I am using Wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I have solved my problem , I just moved `<?php wp_head(); ?>` at start of `<head>` tag in in Wordpress `header.php` and it worked .. strange but it worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

The coda slider plugin is a bit old (jQuery 1.3.2), with an external `jquery.easing.js` that...well, frankly screws up more recent jQuery versions.

I think by far the easiest solution here is to go with another plugin for your coda slider effect, there are several options out there, for example: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/coda-slider-effect/ ([demo here](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/coda-slider.html))

...or, if you're not tied to that effect specifically, there are lots of [other](http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/) [sliders](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2011/03/165-awesome-jquery-sliders-and-other-useful-jquery-effects.html) [out there](http://www.designyourway.net/blog/resources/28-useful-jquery-sliders-you-need-to-download/).